Is it ok to watch censored porn? Like all of the women parts are censored and men's private parts censored
Assalamualaikum brothers I want to ask a question is it ok to watch censored porn? All private parts of women's like vagina or titties be censored and men's parts be censored? Example: Women has a sex with a man but all nudity is censored.

It is haram without a doubt as the awrah are not only the private parts. And you are also not allowed to look at anyone have intercourse even if they are covered or it's blurred in a video.
